# Statement that works in .NET 3.5 throws "error CS0117: 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression' does not contain a definition for 'ParseLamba'" in 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

How can the statement below be converted to .NET 4.5? I was using sampler project code which is version 3.5.

```
LambdaExpression lambdaExpression =
 System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(objectType, typeof(bool), expression);
```

I tried to `System.Linq.Expressions.DynamicExpression` but it doesn't have `ParseLambda` method.

In a project targeting .NET 4.5.1 (or 4.5, it makes no difference), after installing the `System.Linq.Dynamic` nuget package, version 1.0.0, the compiler gives this error:

> error CS0117: 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression' does not contain a definition for 'ParseLamba'.

It can clearly find the class. It just can't find the method. Inspecting the `System.Linq.Dynamic` assembly in Object Browser shows that the method is public and static. So why the compiler error?

Comment: This is a valid question, but needs to be refined to better demonstrate the problem.  In a project targeting .NET 4.5.1 (or 4.5, it makes no difference), after installing the `System.Linq.Dynamic` nuget package, version 1.0.0, the compiler gives this error: `error CS0117: 'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression' does not contain a definition for 'ParseLamba'`.  It can clearly find the class.  It just can't find the method.  Inspecting the System.Linq.Dynamic assembly in Object Browser shows that the method is `public` and `static`.  So why the compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the NuGet System.Linq.Dynamic package, which works for any .net 4.0+ code.

https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic